# typedef, enum, bool, Bool ------confused

Tags: c++, class, constructor, boolean, typedef

I have a logicAND class, the constructor is supposed to evaluate the AND operation of two booleans, and it works this way:

```
class logicAND{
public:
  logicAND(bool a,bool b):value(a&&b){}
  bool output(){return value;}
private:
  bool value;
};
int main(){
  bool m=false;
  bool n=true;
  logicAND t1(m,n);
  t1.output();
}
```

Then, I added some old style macros before the class:

```
typedef enum { False = 0, True = 1 } Bool;
#define bool Bool
#define true True
#define false False

class logicAND{
public:
  logicAND(bool a,bool b):value(a&&b){}
  bool output(){return value;}
private:
  bool value;
};
int main(){
  bool m=false;
  bool n=true;
  logicAND t1(m,n);
  t1.output();
}
```

Now I can not make it work anymore. It seems the major problem lies in the constructor type mismatching.

It is appreciated for pointing out the pitfalls, reasons and solutions.
Thank you!

Comment: ...Should i ask why you want to do this at all?  What's the real goal?

Comment: There's a terrible confusion at the heart of the second fragment you've served up just above.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion at the heart of trying to define a class to do one logical operation on construction.  `bool t1 = (m && n);` doesn't seem to be complex enough to require more code to abstract it away.  About the only point i'd see in it is the ability to plug in operations...but even then, since the operation's done at construction, the code still has to decide on the operation and have a case for each other operation that can be performed....

Comment: "Then, I added some old style macros ".....why?

Comment: Yes, you should have written `#define bool long`, then it would have compiled. And this comment makes as much sense as your example!

Comment: as for the "why": the macros are not my code, but I have to put up with them. To make long story short, after struggled with pages of errors, I tested without the macros, things were good, and I realized the macros were the origin of all the errors.

Comment: And here is the original comments with the macros:
// To avoid ambiguity between bool and char in g++, use the preprocessor
// to rename bool, true, and false to our own enum type

Comment: And how's that "avoiding ambiguity" working out for you so far?

Comment: I think I got hammered and want to punch the person who made the macros -- got the confused the first time I saw them, and more confusion as I tried to extend the code.

Comment: Why use macros? What's wrong with typedef and const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main question is why you would want to do this. What do you want the macros to do, so to say, why do you want the bools to be enums? 
However to see what is going wrong, you have to look at what your codes looks like after the preprossesor has replaced your macros:

```
class logicAND
{
public:
    logicAND(Bool a,Bool b):value(a&&b){} //Expects two Bools which works. Now it trys to do a&&b, this actually is well defined for enums. However it returns a bool (!) which cannot be stored in "value" since that is a Bool.
    Bool output(){return value;}
private:
    Bool value; //This now is a Bool! Not a real bool
};
```

So the reason why it breaks, is that you try to store a the bool returned from a&&b in a variable of type Bool. The obvious way to fix this would be to delte the macros. Or you need to explain why you need them.

Comment: Personally I assumed it was someone experimenting/playing around to see what's what :-).

Comment: Here are the original comments with the macros:
// To avoid ambiguity between bool and char in g++, use the preprocessor
// to rename bool, true, and false to our own enum type

Comment: With the code, it still does not compile:'initializing' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'Bool'....... But a slightly modified version (with a cast) works:   logicAND(Bool a,Bool b):value((Bool)(a&&b)){}

Comment: The code is only what comes out of your code when the preprosesor is finished. To add the cast can solve the problem, thats true. Alternativly you could overload the && operator for your enum type. However I doubt it will result in less confusion, than using the buildin bool type. If you really want to make your own bool type i would suggest to create a class instead of a enum type, and use operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

After `#define bool Bool`, the member `value` becomes of type enum Bool.
You are trying to initialize it with a && b, which is not of type enum Bool, but of basic type bool.
That's why you get a compiler error.

Fix:
Replace the constructor with:

```
logicAND(bool a,bool b):value((Bool)(a&&b)){};
```

Comment: Yes, this cast works... still do not quite understand what's going on.... is the internal "bool" type, as well as "false" and "true" overridden by the macros?

Comment: No. Macros are handled by the preprocessor which executes before the compiler, and it only replaces strings in your source code.